# Printing only the matched pattern between <start> and <end> in sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Input -

```
ajflkajlkaj
ddddddddddd/need/to/print/thiskkkkkkkkkkkk
ahfkjahkfja
```

Output needed

```
/need/to/print/this
```

Googling and tweaking I was able to extract "this" like by doing this-

```
sed -n 's/^.*\(this\).*$/\1/p' myfile
```

but can't seem to get the syntax right for getting the rest of the pattern starting from from "/need".

I would appreciate any pointers/suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
sed -n 's![^/]\+\(.*/this\).*!\1!p'  filename.txt
```

**NOTE**

the `sed` separator can be what you want instead of the default `/`. I use `!` here.

If you prefer, a simple `grep` command will works too :

```
grep --binary-files=text -o '/.*/this' filename.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the response all. Will try and let you know in 1-2 hours.

Comment: Added `grep` solution to my post.

Comment: Both of them don't work. Is it because that the file I'm searching through is binary file? Unfortunately I need to modify an existing file that uses sed, so I'm afraid I have to use sed to keep it consistent.

Answer (score 1):

You need to let us know what the ddd and kkk really stand for. Assuming there is some white space behind "this", you can match this pattern instead:

```
sed -n 's/^[^\/]*\(.*\)\s.*$/\1/p' myfile
```

`[^\/]*` means match as many non-/ characters first.

Comment: Basically I am looking for this pattern in an binary file (core dump file). So the other characters can be any ASCII characters.

Comment: @Kewlemer you may want to use `strings` to get the string literals from the file and grep them for `/`.

Comment: @Kevin  Unfortunately I need to modify an existing file that uses sed, so I'm afraid I have to use sed to keep it consistent.

Comment: @Adam It does not work. Is it because that the file I'm searching through a binary file?